# Pick x (f.e. first) characters from a List entry then pick random entries from the new list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings and i would like to pick a specific number of characters from each string (list entry). I found a bit about slicing strings but I have no idea how to make it work with lists. Also i have no idea if this is the method to go with at all.
Example:
I have a list

```
['abcd12', 'efgh34', 'ijkl56', 'mnop78']
```

and i would like to extract the first two characters of each string `('ab', 'ef', 'ij', 'mn')` and put them in another list.
Any help is appreciated.

edit:
It works now but I have trouble printing the list before slicing. Here's the complete code (the random part doesn't seem to work as well):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random

def generateSequences (n):

    L = []
    dna = ["A","G","C","T"]
    for i in range(int(n)):

        random_sequence=''

        for i in range(10):
            random_sequence+=random.choice(dna)

        L.append(random_sequence)

    print(L)
    return L

def generatePrefixes (p, L):

    S = [x[:20] for x in L]
    D = []
    for i in range(p):
        randomPrefix = random.choice(S)
        D.append(randomPrefix)

    return S, D

if __name__ == "__main__":
    generateSequences(15)
    print (L)
    generatePrefixes(4)
    print (S)
    print (D)
```

It prints S just fine but tells me that L is not defined. The weird thing is that it shows S as undefined as well but it still works.
Also i can't seem to to get the portion where i pick random entries to work. D doesn't show up at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with string slicing and you get following:

```
>>> l = ['abcd12', 'efgh34', 'ijkl56', 'mnop78']
>>> [x[:2] for x in l]
['ab', 'ef', 'ij', 'mn']
```

**Update:** To answer your second question you need to store the return values of your functions and pass them as parameters everywhere they are needed:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    L = generateSequences(15)
    print (L)
    S, D = generatePrefixes(4, L)
    print (S)
    print (D)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still have trouble finding stuff in the documentations since i never know if something is the thing I'm looking for. Could i perhaps ask you to look over the program that generates the list I'm using since i have a slight problem with printing the previous list before i slice the strings.

Comment: Also there is the random part which doesn't seem to work. I extended the question since it's all one program.

Comment: @grindbert: I updated the answer but in the future please consider creating multiple questions in case that the problems are not closely related to each other

Comment: Thank you. I thought since it's the same program I'd better post the problem as a whole to provide context as the problem may have been in the part I didn't post. Thank you for the notion. I'm still not familiar with how to exactly post in a proper form so I'm grateful for every suggestion.

Comment: @grindbert: No worries, you can always link to a previous question in order to provide context. Help center has a whole [section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) dedicated on asking the questions.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I generally am the person to just stumble into somewhere but I will make sure to devour this section.